# Magento 1.9 add to cart slow when cached

Tags: magento, caching, cart, magento-1.9

We have been experiencing an odd issue on some of our sites since moving from Magento 1.7 to 1.9. When a sites cache hasn't been cleared for a while add to cart is extremely slow. This also affect the checkout. As soon as we clear the cache it speeds up again.

I can not really make sense of why this happens. I have tried profiling to see what it is that takes a long time and it seems that mainly the events that take place  **_afterSave** function in **Mage_Core_Model_Abstract** is the culprit.
Mainly the follwing event is run several two times and takes about 10 seconds in totasl to run: **sales_quote_save_after**

cleanModelCache also takes about 6 seconds to run after the save function on the cart have run.

I am looking at our modules that are installed and it doesn't seem like we have any in use utalizing this event.

*EDIT*

After som more testing I realized that the function that taskes a long time is the cleanModelCache function that cleans the following cachetags

```
[0] => quote
[1] => quote_1002 (quote_ID)
```

This function is run twice during the add to cart and it takes about 5 seconds each time. If I clear the cache this is instant.

**edit**
For now we have installed Redis for session management and caching on the server and this seemed to have solved out issue. If it seems like a permanent sollution I will add it as such on this post.

Comment: Which shipping methods are you using? Have you implemented any solution for this issue? are you able to add to cart for less than 5 seconds?

Comment: We use Redis in production. Also, we have migrated all Magento 1.9 instances to OpenMage.